# Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details when making ArrayList

Tags: java

I am making a simple test code to add an element to an Arraylist in JAVA:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class MyArrayList 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("Hello");
        System.out.println(list);
    }    
}
```

But it is returning this error:

```
MyArrayList.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        ArrayList list = new Arraylist();
                             ^
  symbol:   class Arraylist
  location: class MyArrayList
Note: MyArrayList.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Comment: `Arraylist` should be `ArrayList` with a capital `L`.

Comment: There are two separate problems.  The "unresolved symbol" problem (see ^^^) and the "unchecked or unsafe operations" problem.  Both are common problems.  The first has a standard (canonical) answer.  The second is because you are using a "raw" type.

Comment: The `ArrayList` class is a generic type and you should use it with a type parameter; e.g. `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` or `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();` to avoid the "raw type" problem.  Also, it is a good idea to do what the "Note:" message tells you to do!